# I tried to use bitcoin to buy ethereum and failed, what will happen now?

Tags: exchanges, ethereum

I tried to use some at the shifty exchange in the ethereum app, just for research. I sent money to the provided payment adress, but I think I included a to small fee.

My payment is now uncofirmed and in shifty the deal is expired, What will happen now with the bitcoin etc?

Comment: They will get it? They probably are waiting for it to confirm. If you think it's a scam, you can try sending the coins to another wallet you own (using a bigger fee). That will invalidate the other transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitcoin won't magically revert back to your wallet. Contact the exchange and let them know, and they'll handle it, either by processing the exchange or refunding you.